# iOS 11 should push notifications be handled by App Delegate method or solely by UNDelegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, appdelegate, unusernotificationcenter

I have been looking for a straight answer and have yet to come across one so I presumed to ask my question here. With post iOS 10 apps should remote notifications be handled by

App Delegate method:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

}
```

or, UNDelegate method:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

TVOS does not support `UserNotificationsUI.framework` so if you need to support TVOS, stick with the raw `UIApplicationDelegate` method.

Otherwise, the `UNUserNotificationCenter` is my preferred choice if you can stick with post-iOS10 support, as it's likely that the `UIApplicationDelegate` will be deprecated in the future.

If you're using WatchKit, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is deprecated, don't use it. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1628170-didreceiveremotenotification#):

> Instead of using this method, create a delegate object that adopts the
>   UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol and implement the
>   userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:
>   and
>   userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:
>   methods. Assign this object to the delegate property of the singleton
>   UNUserNotificationCenter object.